# Javascript - Compare Integer against an Array of Integers

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to compare an integer against an array of integers? For instance, to determine if an int is larger than any of the array ints?

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
if(5 > array){ 
    // do something 
}
```

Update: I guess I meant, is 5 larger than the largest number in the array. Thanks!

Comment: Judging from your choice of example, I assume you mean "larger than **all** of the array ints"? Or did you really mean "any"?

Comment: @MarkByers. Yeah I think you're right...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
if (5 > Math.max.apply(Math, array)) {
    // do something
}
```

**Update**: To explain as it works. It's described in the docs I linked but I will try to be more clear here:

`Math.max` returns the largest of zero or more numbers, so:

```
Math.max(1, 2, 3, 4) // returns 4
```

`apply` calls a function with a given 'this' value (the first argument) and arguments provided as an array (the second). so:

```
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

console.log(sum.apply(window, [2, 3])); // 5
```

Therefore, if you have an array of integers and you want to get the max, you can combine them to have:

```
console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, [1, 2, 3, 4])); // 4
```

Because it's exactly like have:

```
console.log(Math.max(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

The difference is you pass an array instead.

Hope it's more clear now!

Comment: @gdoron It should :) Which error do you have, and in which browser / js engine have you tested?

Comment: Good to hear! Thanks for the jsfiddle link :) (and the plus)

Comment: In the explaination I had a typo that I tried to fix but @davin was faster than me ;)

Comment: I got confused because of the `Math` in the `apply`. You can use this instead:  `console.log(Math.max.apply(null, [1, 2, 3, 4])); // 4`

Comment: @gdoron, in that case won't be exactly the equivalent and error prone by some javascript implementation. In your case you made the equivalent of `var max = Math.max; console.log(max(1, 2, 3, 4));` but some implementation could expect that `this` (the context object) is `Math` and in your case it isn't. For example, in Firefox is perfectly valid have `console.log.apply(null, [1, 2]);` but it Chrome will raise an error unless you have `console.log.apply(console, [1, 2]);`. So in order to avoid possible error (now or in the future) is preferable use the exact equivalent.

Comment: Do you tested the `Math` or `console` example? The example with `Math` *should* works in Chrome and Firefox, but there is no guarantee that will works in any javascript implementation, because as explained is not the equivalent of the command we want to execute (`Math.max`) because you're changing context object. So the outcome is not necessary the same. As example, I give `console.log` that has different behaviors in different js implementation passing `null`, but the same passing `console`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good and readable built in way of doing it, but it can be done simply with:

```
var bigger = true;
for (var i =0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (5 <= array[i]) {
        bigger = false;
        // you can add here : break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could sort the array, take the last element, and see if your integer is greater than that. Or, you could loop through and check each one. Up to you. The loop is a more performant way.

```
//maybe check the bounds on this if you know it can be a blank array ever
var max = myArray[0];
for(var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {
    max = Math.max(max, myArray[x]);
}

if(500 > max) {
    //do something
}
```